# Blank page when trying to edit contribution profile settings

Tags: contribution-page

When loading Contributions > Manage Contributions Page > Artist Membership > Configure >  Title and Settings >  Profiles > Edit under first option
a blank page is coming up.  I don't see any errors in the logs, but when I inspect it, the following errors come up:

Failed to locate field: contact_1.custom_46 undefined

This is the section of js with the error:

CRM.console = function(method, title, msg) {
    if (window.console) {
      method = $.isFunction(console[method]) ? method : 'log';
      if (msg === undefined) {
        return consolemethod;
      } else {
        return console[method](title, msg);
      }
    }
  };

I'm running the latest version of CiviCRM, on Drupal 7.

Comment: Can you edit the corresponding profile if you access it via **Administer menu » Customize Data and Screens » Profiles**?

Comment: Yes, I can edit it from there.